# Is there a way to create warnings when building (but more importantly publishing) a project in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have a project which uses a system to authorise users.  While I make some updates I want to to be able to set IsAdmin(username) to always return true.  I wont forget to remove this, however it would be helpful if there was functionality in visual studio, like the //TODO, which created a warning or on build or publishing.  Does anyone know of any functionality like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your C# and VB (and C++ in VS 2010) project files are [MsBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx) files and are built using the MsBuild engine.  You could edit your project file in a text editor and add a warning that is conditional on a property being set.

```
<!-- These two targets exist at the bottom of all .csproj/.vbproj files, 
     but are usually empty. -->
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Warning
    Text="This is a debug build!."
    Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
</Target>
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
</Target>
```

You could also make it an error which stops the build using the [Error task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8b08t3s4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I grasp what you want to do, but you'll probably have to use [preprocessor directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28VS.71%29.aspx)s (such as #warning), and maybe combine them? Something like

```
#if DEBUG
#warning This is debug!
#endif
```

Comment: That's idea thanks.  I didn't know #warning existed, but I just wanted some ability to cause a prompt upon build.